# How do I extract fonts using fontforge in a PDF where multiple font objects have the same basefont name?

Tags: pdf, fonts, fontforge

I have this peculiar single-paged [pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2D2rFsfLiPTX2JNTmxQUmtRV2s/view?usp=sharing) which contains a content stream using two different font objects. One happens to be of type TrueType and the other of Type0. Curiously their BaseFont names happen to be the same i.e "ArialMT". How do I extract both these fonts using a fontforge script's Open() function?

EDIT:  As advised by Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans, I'll go a little into why both these fonts are required. The page's content stream uses both these fonts on different parts of the text. In the case where the Type0 variety font is used (on the second line which says "14.99 m2"), the text content is embedded in the content stream as a hex-encoded string (i.e. in PDF's <*hexcharacters*> syntax for hexstrings) with a Identity-H encoding. Thus each two bytes of the string correspond to a glyph which will be mapped using the FontFile2 (TrueType fontfile, object reference: 9 0 R) fontprogram referenced in the fontdescriptor of the Type0 font's descendantfont.
Now all PDF readers seem to render everything correctly, clearly fontforge development haven't seem to take this situation (where two fontobjects with the same BaseFont names are encountered) into account or am I missing something in the scripting language?

Comment: Why do you need to extract both fonts if they're the same font? For that matter, what would you even use a type 0 font for, it's an effectively obsolete virtual font format that really only means something *inside* a pdf file, not outside.

Comment: It is required because the page's content stream uses both these fonts and the content that uses the Type0 variety is encoded as a hexstring with a Identity-H encoding. Now, each two bytes of the string maps to a glyph as embedded in the fontfile stream mentioned in the Type0 font's fontdescriptor. Clearly both fonts are not the same, just their names are!

Comment: Cool: please put that in your post, because it's clearly important information, and you forgot to include it. Please also add all the other information that is relevant to the why and how that is still left out even with the addition of new information you provided. You don't want to end up with many days of [XY question back and forth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) only to end up with "okay so you don't need the type0 font at all for what you *actually* want to do".